# Could not able to reset drop down list

Tags: c#, .net

I am trying to reset a asp:dropdown on save asp:button click. But on postback the drop down retains its selected value. How to achieve this ?

Answer (score 0):

add this when the button is clicked

`myDropDownList.SelectedIndex = 0;`

Comment: I added bro. Still it retains the value from the dropdown list

Comment: SelectedIndex = -1